# My localhost certificate doesn't seems to be accepted

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm actually building my application and using an API for multiple usage purpose and so using Alamofire, I'm working locally ATM but I can't get it to work.

(I have my local nodejs server https correctly running when I hit the API with the browser it's working all fine)

I've generated my own certificate and registered it in the Keychain but when I hit my local URL with a request I get the "code: 1200" from Xcode. But when I hit https://httpbin.org/get it's working all good.

(This is all tested with an Xcode Simulator)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the IP you are using, same as that of your machine ?

Comment: Im using a virtual host with MAMP PRO which is for test purpose only to "mimic" a real domain "api.myname.com" so when I hit the server (hosted at port 443) with a request the url is "https://api.myname.com/user -> GET"

Answer (score 1):

You can pin your certificate or disable certificate evaluation

Use this code for disable evaluation for your localhost:

```
 private static var Manager : Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        // Create the server trust policies
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "your localhost": .disableEvaluation
        ]
        // Create custom manager
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
        let man = Alamofire.SessionManager(
            configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )
        return man
    }()
```

and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54762838/5391914) could be helpful for pinning certificates

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it to works for local development with the answer of a previous thread, this was basically related to the simulator note the certificate since this was working on web and postman:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43877084

Thanks for your answer all, have a good one!